# Errors with Prototype.js on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser, prototypejs

When I run try to access a website using prototype on internet explorer I'm getting the following errors:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know what it could be coming from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check it out : http://groups.google.com/group/prototype-scriptaculous/browse_thread/thread/d013706eb6de2f93?pli=1